# Variable parameter function instantiating an array

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code :

```
template<typename T>
void fillArray(T arrayToFill, int numElements, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    double val;
    va_start(vl, numElements);
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        val = va_arg(vl, double);
        arrayToFill[i] = val;
    }
}
```

I know functions with variable parameter quantities is bad practice, but it's to be used with some old code that's going to be very time consuming to change. if I call it as follows:

```
int myArray[10];
fillArray(myArray, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

it just fills the array with zeroes (or is that the default in c++11?)
Is there something missing here? Should it not be passing the array by reference? I tried usint T& as well but that didn't work either.

Comment: Why don't you just write `int myArray[10]  = {0, 1, 2, 3...};`, or use `std::iota`?

Comment: This is being done in a function for 40 different objects, this is just a simplified example

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue. It could be that I'm mistaken, but the line
    val = va_arg(vl, double);
is incorrect. That assumes the arguments will be doubles. But in your example they were ints. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should pass the array by reference of course (it should be T&). And second, you should actually pass doubles, because your function expects doubles. ints are two times smaller in size (4 bytes) than doubles (8 bytes).

Since you remove all the type checking by using va_xxx, you should care about the correctness of the types you pass yourself.

Means, it should be like this:

```
double myArray[10];
fillArray(myArray, 10, 0.0l, 1.0l, 2.0l, 3.0l, 4.0l, 5.0l, 6.0l, 7.0l, 8.0l, 9.0l);
```

If you don't mind std::vector instead of int[] then you could use variadic templates, which is more elegant and type safe:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void fillArray(T& arrayToFill, Args... args) {
    arrayToFill = { args... };
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> myArray;
    fillArray(myArray, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this method, I just have one question (more about vectors).
The array isn't going to be modified at all after the initial instantiation, will a std::vector in this case be any less efficient than a standard array due to the fact that it has to be able to reallocate on demand?

Comment: It will add a small size overhead; however if you will not modify it, it will not reallocate and act as efficient as a plain array. You can also consider using std::array instead std::array<int, 10> myArray; thus you get stack allocation instead of heap allocation, the performance shoudl be exactly the same as with plain array.